# ActionScript 3.0 Deleting Arrays/chillds after going to next frame

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe

What I have this:

```
var ster:Array;
ster = new Array();

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, groente);

function groente(event:Event)
{
    if(Math.round(Math.random()*140) == 1)
    {
            ster.push(new groente1_MC());
            addChild(ster[ster.length-1]);
            ster[ster.length-1].x = machine.x
            ster[ster.length-1].y = machine.y 
            ster[ster.length-1].scaleX = 0.2;
            ster[ster.length-1].scaleY = 0.2;
    }
    for(var i:int = 0; i < ster.length-1; i++)
    {
            ster[i].y = ster[i].y + 5;
            if( hero.hitTestObject(ster[i]) ) {
                ster[i].visible = false;
                score = score +1;
                Score.text = ""+ score;

            }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, after going to the next frame. I can still see the groente1_MC. And there are still more spawning in my stage. How can i delete all these and stop spawning them after going to the next frame?

Comment: Could you clarify something - this is currently moving your instances of groente1_MC every frame, and occasionally creating new instances. When you say you're going to the next frame, do you mean the next screen of your game?

Comment: When you loos the game. I have this line for an other object too, but then, after 5 hits. you will go back to the main screen to 'play' it again. unfortunately when going back to this frame. I am still seeing these objects (This code is in Frame3. And I am going back to Frame1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the ENTER_FRAME listener to stop the movement and creation of objects, then loop though the array removing each object from the stage before clearing the array:

```
function clearStage():void
{
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, groente);
    for each(var mc:groente1_MC in ster) {
        removeChild(mc);
    }
    ster = [];
}
```

Comment: sorry, there's a space missing. It should be `for each`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
for(var i:int = ster.length -1; i >= 0; i--)
{
        ster[i].y = ster[i].y + 5;
        if( hero.hitTestObject(ster[i]) ) {
            ster[i].visible = false;
            score = score +1;
            Score.text = ""+ score;
            removeChild(ster[i]);
            ster.splice(i, 1);
        }
}
```

example:

```
            var ar:Array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
            for(var i:int = ar.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
                if(i % 2 == 0){                        
                    tf.text +=  i + ' : ' + ar[i] + '\n';                    
                    ar.splice(i,1);
                }
            }
            tf.text += 'so : ' + ar.join(', ');
```

`tf.text` is

> 10 : 10 
>  8 : 8 
>  6 : 6 
>  4 : 4 
>  2 : 2 
>  0 : 0
>   
>  so : 1, 3, 5, 7, 9

Comment: Just a question about this: does it re-evaluate ster.length at the beginning of the loop each time? Wont ster.splice change the length of ster and the loop will do funky things? I just remember I had some something similar in Java once but it might have been a for each loop